# Amazon aws type keys generation

Tags: ssh, security, aws

There is perfect security model when connecting to Amazon AWS instance. But I would like to be able to make such key my self for custom user.
To be clear it will be user with git repository, but it should not matter.

Could be nice if someone give reference to keys in general.